# SE site for architecture design questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question related to the la Sagrada Família's intended design. (In detail, the question would be whether the Nativity Facade, and other parts of the church, will be polychromed as Gaudi intended in his original plans.) Is there any SE site to ask questions like this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no SE site for Architecture. But the closest one I can recommend is

[Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

But make sure your question is [on topic there](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

The on topic page says the following for a good question

- Identify a specific engineering problem
- Require expert engineering knowledge to solve
- Include any relevant drawings, images or references that may be necessary to -
  understand the problem
- Excite or challenge experienced professionals in the field

#### If that doesn't solved your problem, there is an area51 proposal

You can support it at [Architecture & Home design](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102395/architecture-home-design?referrer=xM6RITPuI_bhFc75gWS23g2)

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't be on-topic, since it is really a question on design, not on architectural problem. Let's hope the best for A&HD.

Comment: (it failed....)

Comment: create a fresh proposal, invite your friends. Make use of community promotional ads in each site

Answer (score 2):

I've floated a proposal for an [Architecture](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124342/architecture) site.

Please contribute to building it if you're interested.